# logback and symbolic links

Tags: java, logging, symlink, logback

How can you configure appenders symbolic links in [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)?

I use logback's support for uniquely named files ([described here](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#uniquelyNamed)) to get separate logs for each run.  I would also like to have a symbolic link (e.g. `log.current`) to point to the latest logger file.

Does logback support symbolic link manipulation?  Is there a better way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.  You can ask Ceki to implement it, or subclass the given appender yourself and add what you need.

Comment: With a closer look, symbolic links cannot be created in pre-7 Java without native/external code.

Comment: Symbolic links only make sense on Unix, where you can just call "ln" from Java.